# Drop all constraints in Derby via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

How can I drop all constraints in a Derby database via JDBC?

Comment: JDBC has a metadata api where you can fetch all tables/constraints. With this you should be able to build some DDL Statement to drop the constraints.

Comment: Thanks. If you put that into an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: @ZeissS: just a comment to notify you about the above comment :) @tob: use `@nickname` to notify commenters (the ones who didn't post the original question or the answer) about a respons in comments.

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't know that, thanks @BalusC :)Further I think, Pascal has given a better answer, so I skip providing my own ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could query the system tables SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS, SYS.SYSTABLES and SYS.SYSSCHEMAS to get all constraint names and the related tables for a given schema.

First, a few words about those tables (from [Re: System tables in Derby](http://www.mail-archive.com/derby-dev@db.apache.org/msg13338.html)):

> SYSTABLES has one row for each table in the database. Its primary key is TABLEID, which contains system-generated values. The SCHEMAID is a foreign key column, which references SYSSCHEMAS.
>
> SYSSCHEMAS has one row for each schema in the database. Its primary key is SCHEMAID.
>
> ...
>
> SYSCONSTRAINTS has one row for each constraint in the database (primary, unique, foreign and check constraints). Its primary key is CONSTRAINTID, which is a system-generated value. The TABLEID column is a foreign key referring to SYSTABLES.TABLEID. The SCHEMAID column is a foreign key referring to SYSSCHEMAS.SCHEMAID.

So you could use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    C.CONSTRAINTNAME,
    T.TABLENAME 
FROM 
    SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS C, 
    SYS.SYSSCHEMAS S,
    SYS.SYSTABLES T 
WHERE 
    C.SCHEMAID = S.SCHEMAID 
AND 
    C.TABLEID = T.TABLEID
AND 
    S.SCHEMANAME = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

And then loop and build the corresponding ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT statement.

#### References

- [Derby support for SQL-92 features](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsql9241891.html)

  - Table 22. Support for SQL-92 Features: Constraint tables
- [Re: System tables in Derby](http://www.mail-archive.com/derby-dev@db.apache.org/msg13338.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand why it would be useful to drop all the constraints in your database programatically. Nonetheless, for an example of code which uses the *DatabaseMetaData* API to find various constraints and other dependent objects (views, etc.) for a particular schema in a Derby database, you can have a look at the *dropSchema*() method in the Derby testing harness's *JDBC.java* utility: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/db/derby/code/trunk/java/testing/org/apache/derbyTesting/junit/JDBC.java?view=co